# JavaScript Sets comparison

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Is there are a way to compare sets as a value in JS?

```
> a = new Set([1])
{}
> b = new Set([1])
{}
> a == b
false
> a === b
false
```

but actually I expect that these two sets are equal because they contain the same elements

Comment: I don't ask about an object in general. I ask how to determine the equality of Sets. I guess a Set is intended for comparison. How to determined that two sets contain the same elements?

Comment: Sets are *not* "intended for comparison". The solution is exactly the same as in the duplicate.

Comment: I don't need to compare references. I need to compare the elements

Comment: Give your `Set` class a comparer method, then it should be possible.

Comment: You can write a small utility function : `function compareSets(set1, set2) {
    for (let value of set1.values()) {
        if (!set2.has(value)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}`.

Comment: @ShanShan That won't work if set2 has more values than set1.

Comment: Why not? Sets only contains unique values.

Comment: @ShanShan Try it with `new Set([1,2])` and `new Set([1,2,3])`. Your function loops through the first set, finds that both elements exist in the second set, and returns true.

Comment: You're right, it needs a check before the loop `if (set1.size != set2.size) return false;`. This question shouldn't be flagged as duplicate, a Set is not a plain old object, none of the answers on the other question are applicable.

Comment: In this case, there's no such thing as "Sets", it's just a function with then name `Set`, and it returns an object, hence a duplicate.

Comment: It's part of ES6: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: @ShanShan - I know, and it's just a function that returns objects that are collections of values, hence comparing is the same thing as a regular object, but if you think you have a special answer just for Sets, I'll remove the duplicate. Good luck !

Comment: When even [1] != [1] one should need to write a function for "comparing" arrays as well. And does the need of the OP stop there? Should [[1],[2]] == [[1],[2]] ? This leads to deeper and deeper comparisons.